# Minitab - How to Best Plot X over Y for Large Data Sets

Tags: plot, scatter-plot, minitab

what's the best way to plot X over Y for large data sets. To be specific I have 22 sets of data each containing up to 7500 data values.

[image]

I want to plot column 1 over column 2, 3 over 4, etc., all then being displaied in one diagram. See excel figure below:

[image]

Ideally, all data points are being plotted. Therefore, I would have gone straight to the 'individual value plot'. Since I have vales on the x-axis I would choose 'with groups', unless I can't tell Minitab that it's supposed to asign an x-value to each y-value. This works for one data set, but not for multiple, for which it just never finishes loading.

[image]

Thank you,
Timon